# How to bind the behavior of second script to the first "on click"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code works like this. You click first on `#btn-Preview-Image` the imge is created and then you click on `#btn-Convert-Html2Image` to download it.

What I want to achieve is to download the image with one button, the first one. How to do this?

JS fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = $(".jumbotron"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function() {
        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
            }
        });
    });
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function() {
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });
});
```

Comment: You could move body of `#btn-Convert-Html2Image` event handler to `onrendered` event handler following `getCanvas = canvas;`

Comment: @guest271314 can you take a look at this? https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `<a>` element with `download` attribute set to `data URI`; alternatively,  you can use `window.open()` to open new `window` in a with location set to `data URI`, which should download file

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        var imgageData = theCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/
                      , "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("<a>", {
            href: newData,
            download: "your_pic_name.png",
            on: {
              click: function() {
                $(this).remove()
              }
            }
          })
          .appendTo("body")[0].click()
      }
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3589/

Answer (score 1):

where you want the 2nd lick to happen, just do a click trigger

```
$( "#btn-Convert-Html2Image" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: i added it below `getCanvas = canvas;` without luck

Comment: still having problems?